# Android ScrollView with RelativeLayout

Tags: android, scrollview, fragment, android-relativelayout

I have a fragment with two RelativeLayout, one inside the other. This fragment is inside a tab. I want that the internal layout(layoutInternal) is scrollable, but with the following code does not work. I create the view object into the layoutInternal dinamically. Where is my mistake?

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutExsternal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fragmentHall_10dp_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fragmentHall_10dp_margin">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutInternal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>   
</RelativeLayout>
```

The following code is where i insert the view object (table) inside the intenalLayout.

```
    while (iteratorTables.hasNext()) {
        [...] //Here i calculate the dimension and coordinates
        b_table = new ButtonTable(SelzApplication.getAppContext(),tableMap.getValue(), widthTable, heightTable);

        b_table.setX(Math.round((tableMap.getValue().getX())* Xratio));
        b_table.setY(Math.round((tableMap.getValue().getY())* Yratio));

        //add Touch Listeners to the button
        b_table.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongTuchDragDrop());   
        b_table.setOnClickListener(new TableOnClick()); 


        layoutInternal.addView(b_table, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
```

This is the screenshot of my app. 
[image]

Comment: Your layout code is correct. The view scrolls nicely. Maybe your content view fits the screen and no scrolling is needed. Paste your code from the activity please.

Comment: @SceLus I added the code and a screenshot of my layout. Thank!!

Comment: What is your external layout good for? Have you tried removing it, since it isn't scrollable? If you need your external layout, then I'd recommend you to make it like ScrollView -> RelativeLayout(external) -> RelativeLayout(internal)

Comment: No, I need my exsternal layout and i don't want that it is scrollable, becouse there is another element. I want that the internalLayout is scrollable only.

Comment: Btw: Your relative layout has an orientation attribute, which is only used by LinearLayouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RelativeLayout layoutInternal` has the height initially set as `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` but its content is initially empty because the content is created dynamically; for this reason is not scrollable.

To solve this, when you finish to draw the tables into `RelativeLayout layoutInternal`, you have to set its height dynamically as below:

```
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) layoutInternal.getLayoutParams();
    params.height =  max_y_coordinate_used;
    layoutInternal.setLayoutParams(params);
```