# ScrollView not working in Relative Layout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I'm working on a Login page for my app . The ScrollView isn't working and I'm unable to find out why. I've tried changing the layout_height of ScrollView to wrap_content and some arbitrary value like 900dp and same with the relative layout inside but still no luck. 
When the soft keyboard appears and I fill in details in say 1st editText view and want to scroll down to fill the second one without closing the Soft Keyboard. The page isn't scrolling.
 Here is the Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/register"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:text="New to scheduLAWyer ? Sign Up" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/register"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:text="Login" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:text="Forgot Password" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView123"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/schedulawyer" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/login"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/login"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView123"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email/Phone"
        android:singleLine="true" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: When the soft keyboard appears and I fill in details in say 1st editText view and want to scroll down to fill the second one without closing the Soft Keyboard. The page isn't scrolling.

Comment: Try having a parent layout, say **RelativeLayout** and then place your **ScrollView** inside it. This might help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I solved it myself. The problem was if an background image is added the page won't scroll until the image is bigger than the device size

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your `RelativeLayout` within one `LinearLayout` with `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`. That will give the `ScrollView` content to expand to.

The other, somewhat awkward approach could be to do it programmatically -- as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17545474/451962).

Comment: don't use fill_parent, it was fixed by google now and it is match_parent. I post my answer how I use it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Change the height of the `RelativeLayout`  to `wrap_content`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Praveen: It does answer the question.  It's not correct, but it's an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

// widgets afer this

Answer (score -1):

Try this and see what happens...

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/register"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:text="New to scheduLAWyer ? Sign Up" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/register"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:text="Login" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:text="Forgot Password" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView123"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/schedulawyer" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/login"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/login"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView123"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Email/Phone"
            android:singleLine="true" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: A ScrollView can have only 1 child buddy. Still thanks for trying to help.